# Variable is not showing from sub report to main report in iReport

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I am trying to pass a variable from sub report to main report. I have already declared variable in subreport. But it's not showing when I'm trying to use this at the main report.
Can anyone please help me out?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: check if `report_connection` parameter is added or not. if not 

In propertise of SUbreport , For "Connection/Datasource Expression " select "Use Connection Expression" and add Built in parameter "$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}"

Comment: Built in parameter `$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}` is already added in the properties of sub Report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While returning any value from subReport you have to just type the variable name you declared at the subReport in "subReport variable" field. And at the "Local Destination Variable" you will find the variable you declared in main report. Like this:

[image]

Don't forget to set the variable expression you declared at the main report. It has to be that variable itself.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add the folowing parameters in Properties of your Subreport

- **Parameters Map Expression** : $P{REPORT_PARAMETERS_MAP} : This is used to pass a map containing report parameters to the subreport. The map is usually obtained from a parameter in the master report, or by using the built-in REPORTS_PARAMETERS_MAP parameter to pass the parent report's parameters to the subreport. This expression should always return a java.util.Map object in which the keys are the parameter names.
- **Subreport Expression Class** : java.lang.String
- **Subreport Expression** : $P{SUBREPORT_DIR} + "yourPage.jasper"
- **Connection/Data source Expression**, select **Use connection expression**, and put : $P{REPORT_CONNECTION}

**See also:**

- [JasperReports - Create SubReports](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jasper_reports/jasper_create_subreports.htm)

Comment: I checked this properties. But still the variable I declared at the sub-report is not showing in the main report. I am giving a screenshot for better understanding. Sorry I don't have enough point to upload an image. So, I'm giving a link to the screenshot. You can also look at the properties at the right portion.
 Thanks.

[link]http://s9.postimg.org/jlwwdpm33/jasper.jpg

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge, You need to specify `Parameters` for that sub-report present in main-report based on which it will fetch data. It may help.